# In SQL, does a BETWEEN statement have to be of the form BETWEEN lowest AND highest?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, between

For example, if I did:

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserId BETWEEN 100 AND 1
```

what would the results be?

**Edit:** Sorry, you're right, I should have specified. I didn't want to know the exact number of rows that would return, I just wanted to know if it would return rows that were between 1 and 100 or if it would return rows from `min(UserId)` to 1 and 100 to `max(UserId)`.

Comment: +1 since i'm not sure why this was downvoted - admittedly it could have more detail in it - but if you down vote at least do the courtesy of leaving a comment as to your rationale :)

Comment: +1 Agree. Certainly not bad to be downvoted at all. Andomar has answered the question.

Comment: +1 I can't think of any reason for this to be downvoted! I'd love to know why.

Comment: I downvoted. Maybe I'm just in a bad mood today, but couldn't figure out why trying it or taking a quick glance at the documentation wouldn't have been better.

Comment: It would take less time to just put that statement in an SQL prompt and see what it returns than posting this as a question on SO.

Comment: For those who think he should just try it, what if no rows are returned? Is the query wrong or are all of the ID's out of this range?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
a BETWEEN b AND c
```

is shorthand for

```
b <= a and a <= c
```

So BETWEEN 100 and 1 won't match anything.

Comment: when you say b <= a and a <= c, in this case b = 100 and c = 1, so wouldn't it return 100 <= a (or 100 to max(UserId)) and a <= 1 (or min(UserId) to 1)?

Comment: Matt: no, because intersection of these two sets is empty (AND operator). You would be correct if OR was used.

Answer (score 1):

This probably depends on your RDBMS, but why not just try it out? On MySQL, I get no rows from a BETWEEN 100 AND 1 query whereas I do get rows from asking for BETWEEN 1 and 100.